# Looking for an actuator: is tolerated here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm going to ask a question where I describe my application and write some features I would like from an actuator. My question is about which *kind* of technology might fit the application - I'm not asking for a specific model that fits my specific needs only.

Are these type of questions tolerated here? Or there's a better SE place to ask them?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like it would be fine. But by asking on this site, you're presupposing that it will be an electrical actuator. I understand that you want something that can be *controlled* electronically, but you might get a broader range of possibilities on [Engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Got it. I'm talking about stepper/dc motors/solenoids, etc...